# How to dismiss a View Controller who's transitioning delegate is self?

Tags: ios, transition, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a animated transition set up for my view controller. I have no problem adding a presented view controller onto my current view, but I cannot dismiss the presented view using dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
Also, when the presented view is added, it is a tableView, with selectable cells. When a cell is a selected, a new navigation controller is initiated and is placed on top. When i dismiss the navigation controller, going back to the presented view, the presented view has become full screen, instead of where the animation placed it earlier..

```
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
return 0.5f;


- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
// Grab the from and to view controllers from the context
UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

// Set our ending frame. We'll modify this later if we have to
CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 300);

if (self.presenting) {
    fromViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];
    [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

    CGRect startFrame = endFrame;
    startFrame.origin.y += 220;

    toViewController.view.frame = startFrame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        fromViewController.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed;
        toViewController.view.frame = endFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];
}
else {
    toViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
    [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];

    endFrame.origin.y += 320;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        toViewController.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeAutomatic;
        fromViewController.view.frame = endFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];
}
```

Here is the code for my presented view Controller:

```
shadedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
        shadedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:224.0/255.0 green:224.0/255.0 blue:224.0/255.0 alpha:0.7];
        [self.view addSubview:shadedView];
        dismiss = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [dismiss addTarget:self action:@selector(removeViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        dismiss.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [shadedView addSubview:dismiss];


        detailTableViewController = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithFlag:DETAIL andQRCode:o_qrcodeId];
        //detailTableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        detailTableViewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
        detailTableViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
        //detailTableViewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0f;
        [self presentViewController:detailTableViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```